# How to Create Drop Down Tables In Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: microsoft-access, database

My question is: how do I make multiple drop-down tables in Access? I'm trying to make a table with multiple entries and drop-down tables underneath.

For example:

```
Main file: Car Types, 
Sub File 1: Color, 
Sub File 2: Mileage.
```

How do I make the Color and Mileage from the two sub files appear under the car type file (Main)?

Here are the pictures of my project:

[image]

[image: http://imgur.com/GYqD1bo]

[image: http://imgur.com/MkjfSTA]

Comment: Please upload your images to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get links you can share. [Edit] your question to include the links and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the images for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill do these work?

Comment: Yes, inlined for you ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks. :) Actually, I have a picture of the main table here: http://imgur.com/CJlazuP can that be added as well? I can only enter 2 links...

Comment: Have you created a relationship between the tables?

Comment: @Burgi Yes. I made links between the unique key "Car Type" in each of the Tables coming from the Main Table. http://imgur.com/ON5XFY1

Comment: Its been a long time since I have had to use Access. Leave it with me and I'll do some playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for data entry. You should Try SubForms. 
IN table view, you can only have one table below the Parent table.

Steps you can do :

1. Create form for Parent Table
2. Create TWO subform for Child tables
3. Add these subforms to Parent form